# mean of a probability density function

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

So I'm given this function:

$$
f(t) = 0.5e^{-0.5t} , t > 0
$$

I'm trying to find mu:

$$
\mu = \int_0^{\infty}tf(t)dt
$$

Integrating by parts I end up with:

$$
\mu = -e^{-0.5t}(t+2)\bigg|_{0}^{\infty} 
$$

I'm starting to think, while I write this, that I should take the limit of big N as N goes to infinity to find my mu, but I'm kinda at a loss here.

Comment: When an integral has a bound at $\infty$, it is treated as a limit. This is usually done without mention since in most cases the limit is easy to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $F(t) = -e^{-.5 t}(t + 2)$; then by L'Hospital's rule,

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} F(t) = \lim_{t \to \infty} -\frac{t + 2}{e^{.5 t}} = \lim_{t \to \infty} -\frac{1}{.5 e^{.5 t}} = 0$$

Hence, $$\mu = \lim_{t \to \infty} \int_0^{\infty} tf(t) dt = \lim_{t \to \infty} F(t) - F(0) = 0 + e^{0}(0 + 2) = 2$$

Comment: I like this, but can I take the limit without using L'Hopital's rule? Since e^-0.5N goes to zero, even though it's being multiplied by some large number N, can I say the whole thing goes to zero since the one part for sure goes to zero? I know it's  indeterminate. But taking the limit this way works (at least in this case).

Comment: @ScubaSteve I'm not sure what you mean by "the whole thing goes to zero since the one part for sure goes to zero." In general, indeterminate limits have to be handled carefully and I'm not sure what you're saying.

Comment: Minor point: Exponent is -0.5, not -0.05.

Comment: Ok, I get that. It's indeterminate so its risky to assume the whole thing goes to zero because e^(-0.5t) goes to zero.

Comment: @John Thanks, fixed.